# Finding maximum and minimum values

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given the following sequence of functions,

$$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+nx^2}$$

I am trying to find the points in $R$ where $f_n$ assumes its maximum and minimum values.

Comment: Have you tried setting $f_n'(x)$  equal to $0$?

Comment: In what sense are you comparing functions? Or is max among all functions among all points?

Comment: @Dr. MV so f'n(x) = $\frac{1-x^2n}{(1+nx^2)^2}$??

Comment: Yes.  And $f_n'(x)=0\implies x=\pm 1/\sqrt{n} \implies \sup f_n=\frac{1}{2\sqrt n}$ and $\inf f_n=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt n}$.

Comment: so then sup would be my max value? what about the minimum values

Comment: I augmented the previous comment to answer that .

Comment: @Dr.MV why did you take the derative of this?

Comment: $f_n(x)$ attains local extrema at points for which $f_n'(x)=0$

Answer (score 3):

The result can be obtained without derivatives.

For $x>0$ we have $$1+nx^2\ge 2\sqrt{nx^2}=2\sqrt{n}x$$ so $$f_n(x)\le\frac{x}{2\sqrt{n}x}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$ with equality possible (in case $1=nx^2$, so at the point $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$), so $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ is the maximal value.

Similarily $-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ is the minimal value.

Comment: With your method, how can you be sure the inequality is *tight*? Meaning: I could as well have put $\;1+nx^2\ge 1\;$ ....

Comment: but then you won't have equality for any $x>0$ - this is the key

Comment: Why not? We certainly have that $\;nx^2\ge0\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\;$ ....and you haven't yet answered my last question.

Comment: the fact that equality occurs, is sufficient. I'm not able to find $x>0$ satisfying $1+nx^2=1$, are you?

Comment: That's not the point, but how can we know **with your method** that the upper bound you get is **tight**? How do we know we can't do better...?

Comment: if $f(x)\le c$ for all $x$ and $f(x_0)=c$ for some $x_0$, then $c$ is the best upper estimation for $f$.

Comment: Perhaps I am not explaining myself: how did you know what value to choose to take the bound? How did you know that that bound is attainable and, thus, that it is tight? I mean, how can you know *a priori*, for general cases, what bound to choose?

Comment: I used the simple inequality $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$, which is true as it is equivalent to $(a-b)^2\ge 0$, the equality occurs for $a=b$ only. This is not a general method for finding bounds (and I never claimed it is). It is very elementary and worked fine in this particular case, so I showed my solution just to show an alternative solution.

Comment: @la Ah, that's an answer! Fair enough: it works sometimes, not always...but it did this time. Very nice, thanks. +1